# magento- create table with custom module

Tags: magento

I have a custom module Account_Register. I am creating a custom table called `company_details`. My `config.xml` is -

```
--
<global>
         <models>
            <register>
                <class>Account_Register_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>register_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </register>
            <register_mysql4>
                <class>Account_Register_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <register>
                        <table>company_details</table>
                    </register>
                </entities>
            </register_mysql4>
        </models>

    <resources>
            <register_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Account_Register</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </register_setup>
            <register_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </register_write>
            <register_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </register_read>
        </resources>
</global>
---
```

Account/Register/Model/CompanyDetails.php

```
class Account_Register_Model_CompanyDetails extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('register/company_details');
    }
}
```

Account/Register/Model/Mysql4/CompanyDetails.php

```
class Account_Register_Model_Mysql4_CompanyDetails extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('register/company_details', 'company_details_id');
    }
}
```

and Account/Register/Model/Mysql4/CompanyDetails/Collection.php

```
class Account_Register_Model_Mysql4_CompanyDetails_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('register/company_details');
    }

}
```

I didn't understand what went wrong here.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you receive an error? If so, post it.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\B2BMarkets\app\code\local\Account\Register\controllers\IndexController.php on line 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->_init('register/company_details');` is the problem.

This line of code will, at the end, get you a `Mage::getResourceSingleton('register/company_details')`.

That means that Magento is going to parse the *config.xml* nodes `<models>` after a node `<register>` which it will find in your *config.xml*.
Then it would look at the `<resourceModel>` defined, since it is looking after a ResourceSingleton.

Finding `register_mysql4` in your *config.xml* it will then look at the node having the same name (`<register_mysql4>`) and the `<class>` node below it.

Here, everything is right, Magento can now understand that the `register` part of `register/company_details` is equal to `Account_Register_Model_Mysql4`.

Then it would just capitalise every words in `company_details` : `Company_Details`.
The only thing left to do is concatenate everything and replace the slash `/` with an underscore `_`.

So it get the **class `Account_Register_Model_Mysql4_Company_Details`** which it then could map to the file **`app/code/the_code_pool_given_by_the_module/Account/Register/Model/Mysql4/Company/Details.php`**.
*And that is why it cannot find your files.*

**With your actual implementation what you should actually do is**

```
$this->_init('register/companydetails');
```

in `Account_Register_Model_CompanyDetails`, `Account_Register_Model_Mysql4_CompanyDetails` and `Account_Register_Model_Mysql4_CompanyDetails_Collection` (do not forget the second param in `Account_Register_Model_Mysql4_CompanyDetails` which should be the primary key of your database table)